# How to insert two values with foreach statement in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have small problem here :)

Anyone can help me, what I should do if i want to use this foreach statement with 2 values, because I need to insert in one table at the same time.
Because if I used this code, it will be error. So && is not properly used in this case?

```
$hasilmsisdn=explode(";", $msisdn);
$hasilaccid=explode(";", $accid);
     foreach ($hasilmsisdn as $value "&&" $hasilaccid as $value2)
    {
        $sql = "INSERT INTO complaint_detail (MSISDN,ACCID) VALUES ('$value','$value2');";
        $run=mysql_query($sql);
    }
```

Thanks all, hope you help me :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4480803/two-arrays-in-foreach-loop This is what you are searching for

Comment: You should switch to the `PDO` OR `mysqli` driver and use prepared statements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`array_combine()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php) to combine both arrays as key/value pairs:

```
$hasilmsisdn=explode(";", $msisdn);
$hasilaccid=explode(";", $accid);
$array = array_combine($hasilmsisdn,$hasilaccid);
foreach ($array as $msisdn => $accid){
    $sql = "INSERT INTO complaint_detail (MSISDN,ACCID) VALUES ('$msisdn','$accid');";
    $run=mysql_query($sql);
}
```

While you're at it you should definitely consider [switching](http://www.sitepoint.com/migrate-from-the-mysql-extension-to-pdo/) over to `PDO` or `mysqli`

Answer (score 1):

If both the arrays are having the same size you can use a for loop like this:

```
for($i = 0, $i < count($hasilmsisdn); $i++) {
     $sql = "INSERT INTO complaint_detail (MSISDN, ACCID) VALUES ('$hasilmsisdn[$i]', '$hasilaccid[$i]');";
     $run = mysql_query($sql);
}
```