# How to find id in an array of categories

Tags: php, arrays

```
<?php
  $categories = [ 
          133   => 'Siomay',
          123   => 'Indonesian',
          20    => 'Bento',
  ];

  $input_categories = [
               'Siomay',
               'Indonesian',
               'Bento',
               'Yoghurt',
  ];
```

How to get id categories? The example shown

Results:

```
133
123
20
-1 // Miss (-1)
```

Comment: Why not merge your array's first?

Comment: give me an example :D

Comment: I think you should do this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4480803/two-arrays-in-foreach-loop

Answer (score 1):

To get the IDs in a loop:

```
foreach($categories as $key=>$value)
{
    echo $key . "<br />";
}
```

That will output

```
133
123
20
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume you should show -1 when there is no appropriate value? If it's all about, try this:

```
<?php
  $categories = [ 
          133   => 'Siomay',
          123   => 'Indonesian',
          20    => 'Bento',
  ];

  $input_categories = [
               'Siomay',
               'Indonesian',
               'Bento',
               'Yoghurt',
  ];


foreach($input_categories as $input_category)
{
    if(in_array($input_category, $categories))
        echo array_search($input_category, $categories).'<br/>';
    else
        echo '-1<br/>';
}
```

Output:

```
133
123
20
-1
```

Comment: You should use a counter and print it after the foreach, so it will print the real number of miss

Comment: Hmm... I don't understand what do you mean.. Could you explain?

Comment: The arrays he gave were an example, so with the previous code it would print: -1 <br/> -1 <br/> if there were 2 missing categories, this way at the end prints the amount of missing categories.

Comment: @jonystorm, ut where OP wrote information about counting missing categories?

Comment: I missed the '-' sign on: echo '-'.$counter 

Since there is lack of information, my impression was that he wanted the amount of missing cats, but I can see also that he may not. He should be more explicit

Comment: if  133 => 'Siomay / Waffles / Crepes' ? should not min

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ( $categories as $k => $v ) {
    echo $k;    echo "<br/>";
}
```

if you wants to get category id which exits in $input_category then user this

```
$flipped = array_flip($categories);
foreach ( $input_categories as $v ) {

    echo $flipped[$v];      echo "<br/>";
}
```

Comment: same as the "answer" from Matt, how does this compare if something from `$input_categories` is part of `$categories`??

Comment: so do you wants category id which exists in $input_category?

Comment: how to category mapped? 
example in array  133 => 'Pancakes / Waffles / Crepes',

Comment: Sorry I am not getting what you wants here .. "133 => 'Pancakes / Waffles / Crepes"

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array_keys()` method for this. like below:

```
$ids = array_keys($categories);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($ids);
```