# how to run two foreach loop in one(laravel)

Tags: php, laravel

Hi my code is including two array which I want echo them with foreach() loop in table but there is problem that php won’t let me run two array in one loop

like this:

```
@foreach ($playerinfo1 as $info1 && $playerinfo2 as $info2)
            <tr>
                        <td>{{$info1->id}}</td>
                        <td>{{$info1->authid}}</td>
                        <td>{{$info1->nick}}</td>
                        <td>{{$info1->date}}</td>
                        <td>{{$info1->uses}}</td>
                        <td>{{$info2->rounds}}</td>
                        <td>{{$info2->time}}</td>
                        <td>{{$info2->connects}}</td>
                        <td><a href="http://ip-api.com/#{{$info1->ip}}"> 
{{$info1->ip}}</a></td>
                   </tr>
        @endforeach
```

I tried these codes but they have problem and they echo the value more than once:

```
        @foreach ($playerinfo1 as $info1)
        <tr>
                    <td>{{$info1->id}}</td>
                    <td>{{$info1->authid}}</td>
                    <td>{{$info1->nick}}</td>enter code here
                    <td>{{$info1->date}}</td>
                    <td>{{$info1->uses}}</td>
                    <td><a href="http://ip-api.com/#{{$info1->ip}}">

{{$info1->ip}}</a></td>
                @foreach ($playerinfo2 as $info2)
                        <td>{{$info2->rounds}}</td>
                        <td>{{$info2->time}}</td>
                        <td>{{$info2->connects}}</td>
             </tr>
            @endforeach
    @endforeach

    @foreach ($playerinfo1 as $info1)
        <tr>
                    <td>{{$info1->id}}</td>
                    <td>{{$info1->authid}}</td>
                    <td>{{$info1->nick}}</td>
                    <td>{{$info1->date}}</td>
                    <td>{{$info1->uses}}</td>
                    <td><a href="http://ip-api.com/#{{$info1->ip}}">{{$info1->ip}}</a></td>
            @foreach ($playerinfo2 as $info2)
                    <td>{{$info2->rounds}}</td>
                    <td>{{$info2->time}}</td>
                    <td>{{$info2->connects}}</td>
         </tr>
        @endforeach
    @endforeach

    @foreach ($playerinfo1 as $info1)
        <tr>
                    <td>{{$info1->id}}</td>
                    <td>{{$info1->authid}}</td>
                    <td>{{$info1->nick}}</td>
                    <td>{{$info1->date}}</td>
                    <td>{{$info1->uses}}</td>
                    <td><a href="http://ip-api.com/#{{$info1->ip}}">{{$info1->ip}}</a></td>
            @endforeach
            @foreach ($playerinfo2 as $info2)
                    <td>{{$info2->rounds}}</td>
                    <td>{{$info2->time}}</td>
                    <td>{{$info2->connects}}</td>
         </tr>
        @endforeach
```

Also I used array_combine() in order to combining two array but because of differences between key and value ,it doesn't work

$playerinfo1(array):

```
array:15 [▼
  0 => {#213 ▼
    +"id": 1
    +"authid": "STEAM_0:0:546411185"
    +"nick": "BesTKiLLeR"
    +"date": "2019-05-24 21:22:25"
    +"uses": 62
    +"ip": "188.211.128.180"
  }
  1 => {#215 ▼
    +"id": 2
    +"authid": "STEAM_0:0:21578434"
    +"nick": "ArTTam"
    +"date": "2019-05-23 22:29:43"
    +"uses": 21
    +"ip": "86.55.174.70"
  }
  2 => {#216 ▶}
  3 => {#217 ▶}
  9 => {#223 ▶}
  10 => {#224 ▶}
  11 => {#225 ▶}
  12 => {#226 ▶}
  26 => {#240 ▶}
  32 => {#246 ▶}
  34 => {#248 ▶}
  35 => {#249 ▶}
  38 => {#252 ▶}
  39 => {#253 ▶}
  45 => {#259 ▶}
]
```

$playerinfo2(array):

```
array:16 [▼
  0 => {#264 ▼
    +"id": 1
    +"connects": 65
    +"rounds": 305
    +"time": 38579
  }
  1 => {#265 ▼
    +"id": 2
    +"connects": 37
    +"rounds": 124
    +"time": 17257
  }
  2 => {#266 ▶}
  3 => {#267 ▶}
  4 => {#268 ▶}
  5 => {#269 ▶}
  6 => {#270 ▶}
  7 => {#271 ▶}
  8 => {#272 ▶}
  9 => {#273 ▶}
  10 => {#274 ▶}
  11 => {#275 ▶}
  12 => {#276 ▶}
  13 => {#277 ▶}
  14 => {#278 ▶}
  15 => {#279 ▶}
]
```

I’m afraid if I could not make my point but I hope you will understand what am I mean by looking this code`enter code here`

Comment: How are those two arrays connected? They are of different lengths (`$playerinfo2` has one more element than `$playerinfo1`). How would you handle that? Where does the data come from? If it's a database and there are a reference in one table to the other, then you should just fetch all the data directly as one single array, using Joins.

Comment: Just to answer the question you ask in the title, you can't iterate through two arrays using one `foreach`. One `foreach` can only iterate through one array. There are other ways of solving it though, but then we need more information (like the info asked in the first comment).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4480803/two-arrays-in-foreach-loop shows you how to use two arrays in one `foreach()`, but it assumes that the arrays have the same key value.  You may want to use `array_column()` to create new arrays which are indexed (for example) by `"id"`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Two arrays in foreach loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4480803/two-arrays-in-foreach-loop)

Comment: Try to use relationship [laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#one-to-one)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using Laravel and your data is coming from two tables. Why not use an eloquent relationship?  It would be so much easier.

```php
@foreach ($players as $player)
    <tr>

        <td>{{$player->id}}</td>
        <td>{{$player->authid}}</td>
        <td>{{$player->nick}}</td>enter code here
        <td>{{$player->date}}</td>
        <td>{{$player->uses}}</td>
        <td><a href="http://ip-api.com/#{{$player->ip}}">{{$player->ip}}</a></td>

        <!-- Use a relationship (e.g., stats) to get additional data -->
        <td>{{$player->stats->rounds}}</td>
        <td>{{$player->stats->time}}</td>
        <td>{{$player->stats->connects}}</td>

    </tr>
@endforeach
```

Comment: thank you for your answer i don't know how to exactly do this can you make a relation? my controller(just enter the name):http://collabedit.com/cypyd

Comment: Are these the only two tables related to players, or is there also a main `players` table?  Just trying to figure out how your database is organized.

Comment: And the `id` in each table are the same (e.g., 1 to 1, 2 to 2, etc.)?   On a side note, I'm concerned that your `->unique()` call is potentially destructive.  Records with the same IP will be removed from the results, even if they are different players.

Comment: Also, do you even have any models defined in Laravel?

Comment: yes because my plugin sometimes create duplicate of result so i have to delete the duplicates with unique() by ip

Comment: no i do not have model but if is necessary i can make it

Comment: What plugin?  I'm concerned I just don't know enough about your setup and you don't seem to already be using Laravel's MVC principles.  You may want to take a look at Laracasts to get a good understanding of how to use Laravel as intended. https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-from-scratch-2018

Comment: my whole project is relative to information of game players which the information of them world be confirm on mysql database by plugin automatically but sometimes the plugin confirm the information of players for more than once so i have to delete them with unique() i would appreciate if you make relation for me

Comment: I would really like to be able to help you, but at this point I'm not even sure how your tables are related.  Do the `id`s even match in the corresponding tables, or are you just trying to line them up manually? You are using `->unique()` to delete rows from one set of data and not the other, which will shift data into different rows. How am I supposed to believe the rows in each set of data actually match up with each other?  There seem to be problems with your methods of storing and retrieving data that need to be addressed before I can do anything to help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use array_merge($arr1,$arr2) in your controller
to combine two arrays