# Foreach values from two comma separated strings PHP

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I have two strings that contain information about countries and cities

```
$city = "Munich, Berlin, London, Paris, Vienna, Milano, Rome";
$country = "Germany, Germany, UK, France, Austria, Italy, Italy";

$city = explode(', ', $city);
$country = explode(', ', $country);
```

I know how to foreach trough single array. In the example below I am getting trough country array and add the $value

```
foreach($country as $value) 
{
$data[] = array (
    "text" => $value,
    "entities" => [
      array (
        "entity" => $city
      )
      ]
);}
```

But cannot figure out how to also incorporate the $city array and get the appropriete value.
For example, the expected result is

```
foreach($country as $value) 
{
$data[] = array (
    "text" => France,
    "entities" => [
      array (
        "entity" => Paris
      )
      ]
);}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Two arrays in foreach loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4480803/two-arrays-in-foreach-loop)

Comment: Your expected result _really_ is an `entities` array that will only ever contain _one_ entity each? And _multiple_ items with `text => Germany` in $data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You pick one array and use it to seed the loop, but process both at the same time on the assumption that they're in step.

Here is how it could work with a `foreach` loop:

```
foreach ($country as $key => $value) {
    $data[] = array(
        "text"     => $value,
        "entities" => [
            array(
                "entity" => $city[$key],
            ),
        ]
    );
}
```

And here with a `for` loop:

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($country); $i++){
    $data[] = array(
        "text"     => $country[$i],
        "entities" => [
            array(
                "entity" => $city[$i],
            ),
        ]
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the size of the both arrays would be same, you can do it using one loop like this

```
$i=0;

foreach($country as $value) 
{
$data[] = array (
    "text" => $value,
    "entities" => [
      array (
        "entity" =>$city[$i++]; 
      )
      ]
);}
```

While you are adding the country, keep adding the city using `index` on the city array.