# Two arrays in one table, side by side columns for comparison

Tags: php, html, arrays, foreach, html-table

I am trying to create a html table from two arrays that look like this:

These values are from a wholesaler (remote database):

```
$array1 = array(
     'skucode001' => '0',
     'skucode031' => '2',
     'skucode011' => '1',
     'skucode071' => '54'
);

These values are from my database:
$array2 = array(
     'skucode001' => '22',
     'skucode031' => '3',
     'skucode011' => '5',
     'skucode071' => '231'
);
```

The arrays have all the keys identical and are previously sorted in the same order. Only the  values (stock) may differ.

I need to place all these values so that I can easily compare them and update my stock when they do.

The end result should be a table like this:

```
THEIR SKU    |    THEIR STOCK    |    MY SKU     | MY STOCK
skucode001           0              skucode001        22
skucode031           2              skucode031        3
skucode011           1              skucode011        5
skucode071           54             skucode071        231
```

It would be great if I could highlight the rows that have different stock values (in yellow)
and the ones that have stock 0 on their side, in red.

In the future I will probably remove my sku column, but for now is just to double check what is printed.

I'm too embarrassed to post my code because is a mess and the table is completely broken. It's beyond my skill unfortunately.. Any help will be very much appreciated..

I tried to attach recursively parts of the html code to a variable and then go forward step by step until I appended the whole table. Problem is having two variables with a foreach..

Thank you

Comment: To be able to loop over both loops at the same time - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4480803/two-arrays-in-foreach-loop

Comment: Yes, see the accepted one or the second using `array_combine`.