# Multiple HTML Form fields to PHP arrays via Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I'd like some help. I have the HTML form fields below and I want them to be sent to a PHP page to individual PHP arrays.

HTML

```
<input class="form-control" type="date" onchange="reportSave()" name="testreportname[]">
<input class="form-control" type="date" onchange="reportSave()" name="testreportdate[]">
<input class="form-control" type="date" onchange="reportSave()" name="testreportissue[]">
```

Javascript

```
<script>
    function reportSave() {
        //Test Report Name
        //get the data from test report name
        var testreport=document.getElementsByName('testreportname[]');
        var testreportdate=document.getElementsByName('testreportdate[]');
        var testreportissue=document.getElementsByName('testreportissue[]');
        var data1 = $(this).serializeArray();
            
        //for each item in the array
        for(key=0; key < testreport.length; key++)  {        
                    
        data1.push({
        testreport: $("#testreport").val(), testreportdate: $("#testreportdate").val(), testreportissue: $("#testreportissue").val(),
        });
        console.log("key: ", key)
        console.log(testreport)
        }
        
    //send to PHP via ajax
        $.ajax({
            type: "post",
            url: "draftsave.php",
            dataType: "json",
            data: data1,
            success: function(result) {
                console.log(result)
                }
            });
    }
</script>
```

PHP

```
<?php
$stestreport=$_POST['testreport'];
$stestreportdate=$_POST['testreportdate'];
$stestreportissue=$_POST['testreportissue'];

for($i=0;$i<count($stestreport);$i++)
        { code here, etc};
?>
```

Edit, removed already tried code.

Comment: Does this answer your question regarding iterating multiple arrays at once? [Two arrays in foreach loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4480803/two-arrays-in-foreach-loop)

Comment: You have two similar scripts in your question. I think you only need one? Can you remove the one we shouldn't be looking at?

Comment: There seems to be a lot of fairly redundant messing about in the jQuery code. Are all these fields inside a `<form` in the HTML? If so then you can just [`serialize()`](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/) the form fields and send that to PHP via your AJAX request. Simple.

Comment: @ADyson the fields being part of a form isn't even a requirement, it works on _any_ selection of input/select/textarea elements you pass to it - https://jsfiddle.net/x05u6nps/1/

Comment: If you use `$("#testreport").val()` then the `#testreport` refers to [an id of a HTML tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id). Your inputs only have names, and no ids.

Comment: @CBroe good shout. Never occurred to me to do that but it makes sense now you mention  it. Thanks

Comment: @CBroe Thank you! This works great! So little code and does exactly what I'm after!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery provides the [`serialize()`](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/) function which provides a really simple way to get all the data from a form, or a specific set of fields, and convert them into the form-url-encoded format that they would ordinarily be transmitted in if you submitted a regular form (without AJAX). This is the format PHP recognises and will automatically convert into data in its `$_POST` array.

This little demo shows

a) what serialize() outputs

b) a way to select the specific fields you're interested in using a class name (notice the extra class on each input field in the HTML)

c) a nicer way to handle the "change" event unobtrusively using a selector, rather than littering the HTML with `onchange` attributes.

```js
$(".reportField").change(function() {
  var formFields = $(".reportField").serialize();
  console.log(formFields);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input class="form-control reportField" type="date" name="testreportname[]">
<input class="form-control reportField" type="date" name="testreportdate[]">
<input class="form-control reportField" type="date" name="testreportissue[]">
```

So if you wanted to use it in your AJAX, you'd end up with something like:

```
$(".reportField").change(function() {
  var formFields = $(".reportField").serialize();

  $.ajax({
    type: "post",
    url: "draftsave.php",
    data: formFields,
    success: function(result) {
        console.log(result)
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: I did it slightly differently, but this works too! Thanks!